# using && and || in multiline bash script

Tags: bash

```
echo hello; echo hi
```

is identical to this in a script:

```
echo hello
echo hi
```

How do I do the same to the following possibilities?

```
echo hello && echo hi
echo hello || echo hi
```

I presume I can do this:

```
echo hello && \
echo hi

echo hello || \
echo hi
```

But this is more or less imitating a multi-line script

What is the appropriate way of doing this?

edit: I am aware of how && and || work, I am just wondering how to effectively replicate it in a multi-line script

Comment: || executes the second statement only when the first statement returns failure.

Comment: I see your edit, and apologize for the oversight. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: Using the `&&` or `||` operator between two commands is call a **compound expression** or **compound command**. The operators are a `test construct` between the commands on either side. `&&` says do the `second` only if the `first` succeeds. `||` says do the `second` only if the `first` fails. **NOTE** no line continuation is required after either -- it is implied. Remove `\\` from your code above and confirm.

Comment: It is really beyond my understanding why this question got closed. In my opinion, it is very clear and has a fair point which I now would like to know the answer to too.

Comment: Anyway, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value) is fairly similar.

Comment: In my script file, I did what you presumed you can do but without the `\` and it worked well. I was then able to add comments for each command.

Comment: I think I found the answer in here! https://superuser.com/a/1188001/1284856

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if`:

```
if echo hello; then
    echo hi
fi

if ! echo hello; then
    echo hi
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo one && echo two` prints one, and if that returns 0 it prints two, too.

`echo one || echo two` prints one, and if that doesn't return 0 prints two, too.

You can use it to shorten `if` statements, like so:

`if [[ 1 -eq 2 ]]; then doStuff; fi` shortens to

`[[ 1 -eq 2 ]] && doStuff`

Another example would be my `startx` script I run to update, then startx on my Ubuntu machine

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y autoremove && startx`

What that does is chain `&&` together (remember all `&&` does is check if the command "piped" to it exits with 0) in a way that only the next command is run if the last is run without errors. I do this so that if for some reason `apt` fails me, I can fix it from my terminal without waiting for xorg to do it's thing.

**EDIT:**

If you want to "expand" &&, to more lines use:

```
commandToCheckReturnOf
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    doStuff
fi
```

If you're after `||`, then:

```
commandToCheckReturnOf
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    doStuff
fi
```

Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm not sure if your examples mimic && or ||, but [[]] may be the best method. Eg. command; [[ $? == 0 ]] && command or [[ $? == 0 ]] || command

Comment: It is more pseudo code. `[[ 1 -eq 2 ]]` is obviously always false, and `doStuff` isn't defined, but try plugging some stuff into my example and see for yourself what the difference is. For example, what does `[[ 1 -eq 2 ]] || echo Hello` give you? :-)

Comment: If you're familiar with `$?`, think of `&&` as the shorthand of `if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then command; fi`. And `||` would be `if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then command; fi`. They're not exactly the same but enough so to help you understand the concept.