# How to detect that ftp upload is finished on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, ftp, inotifywait, inotify-tools

I'm using [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)  on CentOS 7 to execute a php script on every ftp upload.

It's working fine, but there is one problem; when the upload gets aborted (for example if I stop uploading or close FTP client) then it still triggers the script.

Is this possible to avoid those situations?

My code:

```
#!/bin/sh
MONITORDIR="/path/to/some/dir"
inotifywait -m -r -e close_write --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
    php /path/to/myscript.php ${NEWFILE}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Thing is: your shell script there contains a sequence of commands.

But you do not have **any** checking if these commands were successful. And you are surprised that they are all executed; even when one failed?!

Depending on how those tools you are calling work, it might be enough to simply add

```
set -e
```

prior calling any commands (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value) for details)

If that doesn't cut it: run your commands one by one; and determine for each one if it failed; and if so; simply exit your script!

Comment: I've tried to add `set -e` at the beginning, didn't help. And how do I determine if each command was failed?

Comment: Well, on a first glance, commands use return codes (and that is what set -e is checking). If that doesn't help ... you simple have to look into each of those commands and figure "how could I determine that it worked"