# Git pre commit hook doesn't exit unless it's the last check,

Tags: git

I had tslint running in my pre commit hook for a while now without issue, and I just added stylelint as well. However I noticed that when I added stylelint tslint stopped working. After some digging around I found the order I declare them in the pre-commit file makes a difference.

For example if this  is my pre-commit file then failures on `ng lint` will be ignored, but failures on `npm run stylelint` exit and block the commit.

```
#!/bin/sh
git pull origin
ng lint
npm run stylelint
```

Here I flip the order of ng lint and stylelint and I find the behavior is reversed, now failures on stylelint are ignored while failures on `ng lint` exit and block the commit.

```
#!/bin/sh
git pull origin
npm run stylelint
ng lint
```

How do I write this so that the commit will be blocked when anything in this returns an exit code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value), which ultimately is what yours boils down to.

Short answer: add `set -e` at the beginning of your script. It'll cause the whole thing to abort as soon as one fails.