# Abort bash script if git pull fails

Tags: bash, git, shell

I have a bash script for deploying a web application which does following steps:

- git fetch
- git pull
- compile files in a release candidate folder
- sync files to live folder

**I want to edit the script so that it aborts if `git pull` fails. How can I check the result of `git pull`?**

Comment: Would this help? [Aborting a shell script if any command returns a non-zero value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value)

Comment: `git pull || exit` ?

Comment: thx for the fast answers i will check it :)

Comment: no because i do not want to exit if ANY command returns a non-zero value

Comment: @123 this worked great