# How to fail a bash script when while/if/etc has errors?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins, groovy

I run a Jenkins pipeline job with Groovy. The Groovy calls bash scripts for each step.

I want to fail the whole job when something in the way has errors.

For Groovy I use the `returnStatus: true`.

For Bash I use `set -e`.

But a bash script with `set -e`, does not exit if, for example, a `while` statement has errors. This is what should actually happen, according to the Linux manual page for 'set'.
I would like to know how to exit immediately in that scenario.

The script:

```sh
[jenkins-user@jenkins ~]$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -xe

FILE=commands.txt

echo "echos before while"

# Run the commands in the commands file
while read COMMAND
do
    $COMMAND
done < $FILE
echo $?

echo "echos after faulty while"
```

Let's say 'commands.txt' doesn't exist.
Running script:

```sh
[jenkins-user@jenkins ~]$ sh script.sh
echos before while
script.sh: line 13: commands.txt: No such file or directory
1
echos after faulty while
[jenkins-user@jenkins ~]$ echo $?
0
```

Although the `while` statement returns exit code 1, the script continues and ends successfully, as checked right after, with `echo $?`.

This is how I force the Groovy to fail, after a step with bash/python/etc command/script returns a none-zero exit code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("A") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def rc = sh(script: "sh A.sh", returnStatus: true)
                    if (rc != 0)  {
                        error "Failed, exiting now..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First question, how can I make the SHELL script to fail when the while/if/etc statements have errors? I know I can use `command || exit 1` but it doesn't seem elegant if I have dozens of statements like this in the script.

Second question, is my Groovy error handling correct? Can anyone suggest an event better way? Or maybe there is a Jenkins plugin/official way to do so?

Comment: A bit late, but did you get a solution to this, i.e. having errors in bash built-ins automatically detected? Thanks for letting me know 'while' is not covered by '-e'. One more reason to code defensively, i.e. `[[ -f $FILE ]]`, before using it.

Answer (score 1):

First question this link may be helpful [Aborting a shell script if any command returns a non-zero value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value)

Second question: You can improve your error handling using try and catch for exception handling.

```
 try{
       def rc = sh(script: "sh A.sh", returnStatus: true)
       if (rc != 0)  {
                error "Failed, exiting now..."
       }
    }  
    catch (Exception er){
         errorMessage = er.getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why to add the try/catch on top?

Comment: Do not add try/catch at top add try/catch within your stage block. Try/catch helps in separating error handling from regular code.

Answer (score 1):

About the Bash script.

Your issue is that the fail redirection does not abort the bash script, despite the use of `set -e`. I was surprised my-self. But it's my first disappointment about `set -e`, so now I consider to not trust it and I abuse of stuff like `$command || exit 1` ...

Here you can do the following:

```
set -xe -o pipefail
cat $FILE | while read command; do $command ; done
```

But the whole loop should be simplified into:

```
bash $FILE
```

Comment: For clarity (and for careless readers like me): adding `-o pipefail` to the original question does not change its behaviour. One needs to turn it into a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `while` exit code and return it? (See this modified version of your script, the last lines)

```
[jenkins-user@jenkins ~]$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -xe

FILE=commands.txt

echo "echos before while"

# Run the commands in the commands file
while read COMMAND
do
    $COMMAND
done < $FILE
status=$?

echo "echos after faulty while"

exit $status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[jenkins-user@jenkins ~]$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -xe

FILE=commands.txt

echo "echos before while"

# Run the commands in the commands file
while read COMMAND
do
    $COMMAND
done < $FILE
echo $?

echo "echos after faulty while"
```

When yor perform a `echo $?` after this script it will always be 0, because the last command was `echo "echos after faulty while"` you can ad an `exit 1` at the end of your script. In `exit 1` the number 1 will be the error code, you can use other. So the script will be

```
[jenkins-user@jenkins ~]$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -xe

FILE=commands.txt

echo "echos before while"

# Run the commands in the commands file
while read COMMAND
do
    $COMMAND
done < $FILE
echo $?
exit 1
```

Comment: I think the poster's point is that it should never reach the `echo "echos after faulty while"` line, since they have a `set -xe` at the top; it should exit when the while loop fails.