# How to perform string validation in Shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I need to do validation on `git clone [bitbucket Git URL]`using shell script.
Running the above command gives  `fatal: destination path 'sweta-test-parameter' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

I need to write an if-else condition where it checks if the clone command gives a fatal error don't proceed or else do  `git add remote origin`
What regex should I use to do that validation?

Can someone please help?

Appreciate all your help! Thanks!

Comment: It will be easier to exit the script if `git clone` fails than to validate the string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value

Comment: Thanks Lars for your reply and for sharing the information. How can I inform the user that the project already exists rather than closing the command prompt as soon as the error occurs. I mean the user should why the ` git clone could not happen `

Comment: Print the output from the failing command, and maybe also print the commandline itself. You will most likely not be able to interpret every possible error message from `git clone` in your script, so I wouldn't even try. You can also print something like "This could fail because the project already exists", if that is a common mistake for the user in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much Lars for your reply and for sharing the information.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack would be to redirect the `STDERR` generated from the command :`git clone [bitbucket Git URL]` to a temp file and then print the error if the return code of the command is not equal to `0`... :

```
git clone [bitbucket Git URL] 2>/some_path/error.txt
if [[ "$?" -ne '0' ]]
  then
    printf "The error encountered on git clone is : $(cat /some_path/error.txt)\n"
else
  git add remote origin
fi
```