# Why is the exit status of a program important?

Tags: c, operating-system, exit, status

Are there any other reasons why we need exit status in a program other than that it'll help the operating system to check if the program is successful?

For example, in C we write `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`. Is it just to show the C program that the code is done?

Comment: It's important if the exist status is to be used by the program that lauched your program, for example shell scripts. For your C program itself it's irrelevant.

Comment: Successful exit in just one aspect, consider the many scenarios where it can fail, a specific exit status will let you know why exactly it failed without an immediate need to dig deeper.

Comment: To control the logic in a batch file. For example, if the compiler was unsucessfull, don't call the linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, it is for a parent program, such as a shell or batch file, to see if the program was successful.

For example, in a shell script, [using the `set -e` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/821419/13592914), the shell script will exit if any simple command returns a non-zero value.

Similarly, in a Makefile, if any compilation fails, it will exit the Makefile (Unless otherwise specified, I believe). This is used to stop compilation if a file is unable to be compiled.

Also, different exit codes can signify different errors. A code of `0` signifies success, while a non-zero value (1-255) represents failure. As said  by the [GNU bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html#:%7E:text=If%20a%20command%20is%20not%20found%2C%20the%20child%20process%20created%20to%20execute%20it%20returns%20a%20status%20of%20127.%20If%20a%20command%20is%20found%20but%20is%20not%20executable%2C%20the%20return%20status%20is%20126.), an exit code of 127 represents the command attempted to be executed could not be found, and 126 represents the file is not an executable.