# How to exit from a shell script if cmake build fails

Tags: cmake

I want to write a shell script in which am going to use cmake build:

```
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

After these 2 statements more statements are to be added in the script.
But if the cmake build fails the shell script should exit.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please see: [Aborting a shell script if any command returns a non-zero value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821396/aborting-a-shell-script-if-any-command-returns-a-non-zero-value). The question post shows how to exit if a specific command fails, and the answer shows how to exit if any command in a script fails.

Comment: You should edit to say (by tagging and by stating) exactly what shell scripting language you want and answer for.

Answer (score 0):

try add `set -e` in front of the script
bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html
but it should also work with sh/zsh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/sh
set -e

echo foo
false
echo bar
```